# How can I send url with user's unique_id and token in Django?

Tags: django, django-csrf

I created a Django App ("Invigilator Management System") for college. I didn't include any login authorisation as it will be only used by college adminstrator. In this app, I have one task left, I have to send availability form in mail for all the users which are in database asking for them to fill form whether they are available for that day or not, based on their response I have to store their availability status in database. How can I send form in mail?
or should I send them a link for the form ?
If I have to send link, how can I prevent one user accesing other user's form just by changing link they got, any idea how to add token along with thier unique id ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Send email with unique token.

**Generate token:**

Generate random token using user's fields as salt.
Can be any field one or more than one like first name, last name, user id, etc.
Seems like you don't have large user base, and there is less probability of duplicated token.

**How to generate token?**

There are many package which can help you generating random token.
As per my experience I found `uuid`, `secrets`, `hashlib` helpful, of course these are python built in libraries.

Example:

```
# recommended, uuid guarantees uniqueness.

>>> import uuid
>>> print(uuid.uuid4().hex)
'772d4c80-3668-4980-a014-aae59e34b9b9'

# others way, some sort of salt combination

>>> import secrets, hashlib
>>> first_name = user.first_name  # pull user first name, a salt.
>>> salt = secrets.token_hex(8) + first_name
>>> hashlib.sha256(salt.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
'f8b2e14fe3496de336017687089fb3c49bcab889ac80545fc087289c5b1a3850'
```

Generating random token is pretty easy, and next.

Now store your random token in your database respective to the user, depending on the token generation method used, we may have rare possibility of duplicate token. Make sure you cleanup expired token regularly.

When you use salt combination method I recommend you to check the token existence and regenerate if so.

Example unique token model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils import timezone

class UserUniqueToken(models.Model):
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    token = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    datetime = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)  # for token expiration
```

**How to check token validity?**

`views.py`:

```
from .models import UserUniqueToken
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.utils import timezone
from datetime import timedelta

@login_required
def user_form(request, token):
    user_token = get_object_or_404(UserUniqueToken, token=token)  # get object or throw 404
    if not user_token.user_id == request.user.id:  # check token belongs to the user 
        # token does not belongs to the current user, do something 
    time_now = timezone.now()  # current time
    if user_token.datetime > (time_now - timedelta(hours=2)):  # check if stored time exceeds 2 hours
          # do something with expired token here.
    return render(.............)  # successful, render or throw success response
```

`urls.py`:

```
from .views import user_form

urlpatterns = [
        path('form/<string:token>', user_form, name='user-form'),
]
```

You may also consider deleting the expired tokens in days interval like so as expired ones will be obsolete by time.

Comment: Thank you for this, also how can  this be extended to make temporary url?
For example, If I sent email in 8 am and url should be expired in 10 am(not fix can be any).